# How can I change the date range for the MRP Exceptions data?

Tags: acumatica

I want to change the date where the MRP Exception data (created using the Regenerate MRP process screen) cuts off (as of now, it seems to use the current business date).  I found the following logic in the **MRPEngine** BLC, and I think this is where I would add an OR, using a custom field to add an additional date to the following BQL statements:

[image]

```
      ....
```

[image]

so - my question is, is there an easier way to add an additional date (ORed to the current business date) to the where clause in this method without re-writing the entire business logic / associated methods included in this call?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way will be to overwrite that function in a graph extension

```
  public class MRPEngine_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.AM.MRPEngine>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
    public delegate void MrpExceptionsAllDelegate();
    [PXOverride]
    public void MrpExceptionsAll(MrpExceptionsAllDelegate baseMethod)
    {
      //do your changed logic here
    }
    #endregion
  }
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Wouldn't I have to re-create all that logic that's  in the original method?  Can I just cut out a section of code (in the image above) and re-write it - and the original method will just replace that part?  I have no idea...

Comment: @pmfith yes, you would have to re-create the logic. There is no available way to just adjust that explicit selection.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Thanks.  I did that and I think it worked...  ;D